# SSH / SFTP is not correctly executed from IIS in .NET Application

Tags: .net, iis, ssh, sftp

I took over a .NET application and the application is run under an ApplicationPoolIdentity User with LoadProfile set on True.

The Application executes ssh and sftp commands from the windows cmd. But since the ssh host changed its IP, the commands don't seem to work any more. We're using the standard OpenSSH client on a Windows Server.

Is there a possibility to try and run these commands manually under the ApplicationPoolIdentity user?

I already tried the following

- succesfully connected and executed GET and PUT with my own user account
- checked and set the permissions on the ssh and key files
- checked with the destination server
- checked port and IP
- Tried using FQDN
- Updated the know_hosts file

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Can't SSH to server when IP changed? Did you receive any error messages? It's hard to understand what's going on by description alone.